# Why does my RCX programmable brick have no power socket?

Tags: rcx

My RCX has no power socket, I don't know why. it seems that all RCX 1.0 over #300000 have no power adapters. My ONLY link is Google pictures. why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The LEGO Group removed the power adaptor on RCX bricks included in the Robotics Invention System 1.5 onwards - These are [often referred to as 1.1 or 1.5 bricks](http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/9747-1).

Comment: Really late, but... I thought the power adapter wasn't removed until the RIS 2.0. And I'm almost certain that there was no RCX 1.1, but rather a 1.0.

Comment: Hmm, indeed - the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Mindstorms#RCX) now refers to the 1.0s as being without the power adaptor ("In version 2.0 (as well as later 1.0s included in the RIS 1.5), the power adapter jack was removed."). I'll need to check the one I've got at home - it's definitely a 1.5 set and I'm pretty sure it doesn't have a power adaptor and isn't marked 2.0